# In Atom, is there a way to search only in files whose name match a regex?

Tags: regex, search, atom-editor

I use Atom as my primary coding environment, and generally I love it. There is one feature that I could really use right now, and I'm not sure if it exists or not.

Basically, I want to do a project-wide search for a string ("1.1.0"), but I only want to search within files that have the word "build" in them. I know that Atom allows me to search a file/directory pattern, such as src/assets or even src/assets/*.cs or src/assets/buildFile.*

But in this particular project there are tons of files that have the world build - CustomBuild.xml, BuildScript.cs, FinalBuild.xml, etc. Is there any way that I can tell Atom to search for my query string in a regex-defined file/directory pattern? (I'm also open to other ways of solving my problem)

Thank you for your time!

Update: Just to clarify, some things I've tried so far:

1. Searching using "*build*" for my file/directory pattern (only returns file names that are build.*)
2. Using */**/*build*.*  (same issue)

Comment: Can't you just use ctrl+p to search and open a file that way?

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Doesn't something like `*build*` work?

Comment: @wanderer0810 I suppose that I could open up each file with "build" in it, one by one, and do a single-file search. But I was wondering if there were an easier way within Atom, since I have at least 32 files with "build" in the name. If I were to go that route I may as well just write a shell script instead.

Comment: @SemperCallide Ok, I see. I think that writing a shell script would be your best bet, but I don't use atom very much so someone else could know something I don't. Best of Luck!

Comment: I think the problem is that the file/directory pattern is case-sensitive. `*build*` will match `foobuildbar.anything`, but not `fooBuildBar.anything`. Not sure how to fix that, except searching for first `*build*` then `*Build*`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Or `*uild*` ... :)